# What should i do if i want to set two parameters in jpa with query.setParameter ?

Tags: mysql, jpa

More specifically i have 3 entities(doctors, patients, prescripts). The prescripts entity has two foreign keys refering to doctors and patients. So what i want to do is find prescripts by patid and docid. The problem is i can set two parameters using query.setParameter so what do i have to do?

```
public List<Prescripts> findByDocid(Doctors fbd) {

TypedQuery<Prescripts> query = em.createNamedQuery("Prescripts.findByDocid",
Prescripts.class);
List<Prescripts> prescripts = query.setParameter
("docid",fbd).getResultList();
return prescripts;
}
```

If you want more code, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Prescripts> prescripts = 
    query.setParameter("docid",fbd)
         .setParameter("patid", patId)
         .getResultList();
```

Or, if you prefer avoiding chaining calls:

```
query.setParameter("docid",fbd);
query.setParameter("patid", patId);
List<Prescripts> prescripts = query.getResultList();
```